Is this plaster wall ok to paint?
I had a very damaged drywall, with poorly looking edge by the ceiling, showing cracks and bubbles in the drywall. I managed to repair it with an anti cracking filler. This left me with somewhat uneven area which I decided to sand down. Unfortunately while sanding with a random orbital sander I’ve gone through to the plasterboard, which couldn’t be avoided due to rough patches I was trying to smooth.
While I was at it I also sanded the rest of the wall since the painted plaster had a lot of texture and more ugly spots.

I know the areas where I’ve gone through to the bare plaster need covering (I’m going to use EasiFiller which is for filling holes but it’s easy to work with and can be applied in very thin coats, and then lightly sand it down), but apart from this is the wall ok to seal and paint? I’m slightly worried that I have overdone it with how much I sanded it
Texture of the wall before sanding:
And after (it is smooth to touch, the weird way light bounces off the wall here is more like a halo effect left after random orbital sander):


Cracks in corners is common, but bubbles is usually not common.  Bubbles are usually caused by bad drywall finishing or moisture.  If caused by moisture(pipe leaks, roof leaks, wall leaks), that needs fixing before any finishing of drywall is done.

Thanks, there were no leaks as there are no pipes in that area, it was probably really bad finishing as I can find similar poor finishing jobs throughout the property. Any advice about ready for painting this wall is as pictured?

Fix/smooth out any imperfections in the wall before painting.  Drywall mud feathered/smoothed out over 12 to 18 inches can hide most imperfections from a flat surface.  Fingers might be better at feeling imperfections than eyes, depending on the light source.

You really have three questions and you should find their separate answers: 1) Paint naturally peeling or bubbling -- you need to know why, and to fix the cause, 2) Preparing the wall after your aggressive sanding 3) the wall is not flat.  If you want to fix that, you need to build it up with plaster.  There are lots of youtubes on that.  A skim coat would solve #2 AND #3 but IMO that's very advanced for DIY.   The easiest would be to prime it as is and accept the wavy wall.  A professional skim coat will not need sanding, it will finish like glass.

Paint will enhance any imperfection.
So if you see an imperfection before paint, you'll see it more clearly with paint (not to mention seeing the ones you didn't notice before paint.)
As such, the more "perfect" you get the wall before paint the better, unless you're going to go the other way and texture it to death in an attempt to hide the imperfections.

The term for which to search is skim coat.  If you skim coat over what you have now, you can sand the skim coat smooth.
In general, it is better to fix by building up rather than sanding down.  Sanding works better on what you add than what is already there.
I'm not the person to give you advice on how to skim coat but others here are.  If you don't get a better answer to this question, you might post another question specifically about skim coating.  Or try reading the questions behind the link.  Not specific to your situation but some may be close enough to be helpful.
